# Show that $g \circ f \circ g^{-1}$ is the $m$-cycle $(y_1, y_2, ..., y_m)$ with $y_i := g(x_i)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations

> Let $f = (x_1, x_2, ..., x_m)$ is $m$-cycle and $g$ is a permutation
>   of the set $E$.  Show that $g \circ f \circ g^{-1}$ is the
>   $m$-cycle $(y_1, y_2, ..., y_m)$ with $y_i := g(x_i)$.

For example, if $f = (1, 4, 3)$ et $g = (1, 2) \circ  (3, 4, 5)$ is a permutation of the set $\{1,2,...,9\}$,  then $g \circ f \circ g^{-1} = (g(1), g(4), g(3)) = (2, 5, 4)$.

I tried to do the exercise, but I can't find. Are there anyone who could give me a good hint to solving this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Apply $g\circ f\circ g^{-1}$ to $g(x_i)$.

$g\circ f\circ g^{-1}(g(x_i))=g\circ f(x_i)=g(x_j)$, where $f(x_i)=x_j=x_{i+1}$ if $1\leq i<m$ and $f(x_m)=x_1$. Now let's put this in terms of the $y_k$'s you've got:

$g\circ f\circ g^{-1}(y_i)=y_{i+1}$ for $1\leq i<m$ and $g\circ f\circ g^{-1}(y_m)=g(x_1)=y_1$. Therefore, $g\circ f\circ g^{-1}$ corresponds to the $m$-cycle $(y_1,...,y_m)$ with $y_i:=g(x_i)$.

Comment: Could you answer this question? I can't resolve the problem.

Comment: @J.G I've edited my answer to give the solution.